# I fail to allocate stack variable - 8086 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, stack, x86-16

I try to write a procedure that gets a string and make copy of it on the stack.

that's my code:

```
cpyStr proc
    mov bp, sp    
;   save the IP
    mov bx, sp
;   copy the counter loop
    mov cx, [bp+4]
;   make local variable - need 30 bytes
    sub sp, [bp+4] * 2; length is byte so duplicate for word ...
;   copy the string's offset
    mov si, [bp+2] ; offset to si
copy:
    sub bx, 2 ; next word
    mov ax, [si] ; store the character in ax
    mov [bp], ax ; copy to stack's currect word
;   to the next .. 
    add si, 1 ; go to next character
loop copy
;   print
    push bx ; send local string var as parameter for printStr
    call printStr 
;   return the IP
    push    bx
;   returtn to main ....
    ret 4 ; delete 2 parameters 
endp ; end
```

main:

```
start:
    mov ax,@DATA
    mov ds,ax
; print
    push strSize
    push offset string
    call cpyStr
; msg
    push offset passed
    call printStr
; end
    mov ah,4ch
    mov al,0
    int 21H
end start
```

Data segment:

```
string  db "Heello$"
strSize dw  8
passed  db "Passed$"
```

For some reason it does not process successfully.

Answer (score 1):

You have at least three problems.

First, your copying starts by writing into [bp], overwriting the return address of the function. Your stack buffer starts at [sp].
Second, you traverse the source buffer going forward and the destination buffer going backward, reversing the string.
Third, you jump by 2 bytes in the destination buffer but only by 1 byte in the source buffer.
The correct code should look more or less like this

```
    cpyStr proc
    mov bp, sp
    mov cx, [bp+4]
    sub sp, cx
    add cx, 1
    shr cx, 1
    mov si, [bp+2]
    mov bx, sp
copy:
    mov ax, [si]
    mov [bx], ax
    add bx, 2
    add si, 2
    loop copy

    push sp
    call printStr
    mov sp, bp
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried - why does SP is FFDE? http://img444.imageshack.us/img444/8631/13392070496877.png

Answer (score 0):

Should it not be: `string db "Hello", $` in the data segment as well as `passed  db "Passed", $`

Comment: The $ sign has to be outside the string like this: `string db "Hello", $`

Comment: It is not the problem. I always using inside $ sign and I have never problem with it. I'm sure the problem is in the cpyStr proc.

Comment: How does your `printStr` routine look?

Comment: It print a number as string (because assembly doesn't support numbers print). something like a printf("%d"). it's works 100%..

Comment: If you would post that code it would help to debug your program.

Answer (score 0):

Should the code not be:

```
loop copy
mov sp, bx
pop sp           ;pop instead of push
call printStr

ret 4
endp
```